# What is the name of the "=>" keyword in Scheme?

Tags: scheme, sicp

[Excercise 4.5](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-26.html#%25_thm_4.5) of Structure and Interpetation of Computer Programs (SICP) introduces an alternative cond clause syntax of the form `(<test> => <recipient>)`, e.g.:

```
(cond ((assoc 'b '((a 1) (b 2))) => cadr)
      (else false))
```

Is there a name for this keyword or for this alternate form of the cond clause?

A procedure to test for the presence of this keyword could be of the form `(=>? <exp>)` but I might prefer a more expressive name.  Even if use the name `=>?` is there a recognised way to pronounce this, e.g., "is double arrow", "is altnernative cond clause", "is calling cond"?

I have scanned a couple of r*rs specs but I couldn't see the keyword referred to by a name.

Comment: In other programming languages I have heard the `=>` symbol called "fat arrow".

Comment: @exnihilo Thank you, I think "fat" arrow is less ambiguous than double arrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Scheme supports an alternative clause syntax:
>
> (predicate => recipient)
>
> where recipient is an expression. If predicate evaluates to a true
> value, then recipient is evaluated. Its value must be a procedure of
> one argument; this procedure is then invoked on the value of the
> predicate.

So you read it like in logic "If *predicate* then *recipient*".  With the constraint that *recipient* is a function of 1 argument.

UPDATE:

I checked the [mailing lists of scheme](https://groups.csail.mit.edu/mac/ftpdir/scheme-mail/HTML/) and I have never seens this syntactic sugar, which means, it is a recent addition to the syntax.

Comment: Thank you, given there doesn't seem to be a formal name for the keyword, nor this type of cond clause, I'm currently calling the the procedure that tests for this form 'cond-recipient-clause?' mirroring the name of the produre in the book's metacircular evaluater 'cond-else-clause?'

Comment: @codybartfast  I quoted from the manual of mit-scheme, but when it's about scheme, first you look at the definition in RnRS.  http://www.r6rs.org/.  Here, it's defined << If the selected hcond clausei uses the =>
alternate form, then the hexpressioni is evaluated. Its value
must be a procedure. This procedure should accept one
argument; it is called on the value of the htesti and the
values returned by this procedure are returned by the cond
expression. " >>  So you can choose how to name it, but "if ... then ..." it's a suggestive name, like an operator of logic.

Comment: @codybartfast I have never seen somebody to have coined a name for this syntactic sugar.  You simply read it as a logical operator.

Comment: @codybartfast I think this notation is quite recent, it was not present in 1986 in the original definition, so it may be inspired from other languages.  But in scheme it does not have a name.  You can also browse the source code of mit scheme and see the comments in implementation.  I am writing from phone now.

Comment: Thank you!  - I was just hoping there was a commonly used name, even if there wasn't a formal name.   It hadn't occured to me that it was a relatively new addition to the language (I don't see an equivalent question in the 1st edtion of the SICP), it's all making a bit more sense now :-) Thanks again.

Comment: @codybartfast sicp appeared in 1986 and the lambda papers a few years before. When sicp appeared, there were already many implementations of scheme.  At mit there were 2 implementations of scheme, sicp presents the student's version.  At that time they focused on the semantics of the kernel language.  I cannot say what is the origin of this syntactic sugar.

Comment: @alinsoar [Page 13 or RRS from 1978](http://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/6283/AIM-452.pdf) shows the `=>` in `cond`

Comment: @Sylwester -- interesting; the fat arrow syntax was [described as implementation-dependent in R3RS](https://groups.csail.mit.edu/mac/ftpdir/scheme-reports/r3rs-html/r3rs_6.html#SEC30) and in [R4RS (p. 9)](https://people.csail.mit.edu/jaffer/r4rs.pdf), before it became a guaranteed part of the language in R5RS. Any way you slice it, this doesn't really seem like a _recent_ innovation....

Comment: @Sylwester interesting.  Thanks.  I will ask some friend what is the origin of this operator and I will update here.

Comment: On the subject of what to call these clauses (in spoken language, or a languange like C), I've been looking for its use in sentences.  Not surprisingly I've only found the symbol `=>` used, e.g., SFRI 61 (A more general cond clause) contains _"... as in the => clauses ..."_ which suggests to me these should be called '(fat) arrow' clauses, partly to be close to the written representation, but also this SRFI describes <generator> <guard> on the left instead of <test/predicate>, and it's possible a future SRFI might describe something other than <receiver/recipient> on the right.

Comment: @codybartfast much of the language of computer science (used by scheme and not only) is imported from the mathematicians/logicians (Goedel, Tarski, Curry, Schonfinkel, Frege, Herbrand, Church, etc, etc), and it is instructive to read them in original to be a better programmer and understand better.  I will ask a friend about the origin of the "=>" in cond and will update the post.